# Why is Visual Studio Code during debugging showing the output values inline multiple times?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

### Context

I'm using Visual Studio Code and am trying to debug a method. The method takes in an array of integers. I have enabled "show output values inline" during debug, so I can see what values are contained in what object. The funny thing is the nums array gets printed/outputed multiple times in some lines.

### What I expected

The nums ouput to be shown only once in the single line, since it is only mentioned once in that particular line.

### What I encounter

The nums ouput is shown multiple times in every line it has been mentioned and it get's messy.

[image]

```py
    class Solution:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # added a function breakpoint for two_sum
    def two_sum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                if (nums[i] + nums[j]) == target:
                    return [i, j]

nums = [2, 5, 5, 11]
target = 10


solution = Solution()
solution.two_sum(nums, target)
```

Comment: It looks like you've enabled some kind of debugging output in VS Code that displays the value of each variable on every line of code.

Comment: a similar bug has been reported before: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129770. I recommend reporting an issue ticket (use the `Help: Report Issue...` command in [the command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) and providing a [mre], and pointing to that past issue ticket and asking if anything has regressed. If you do that, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Comment: do you have any Python / debugging extensions installed? If so, what are they, and what version of them do you have installed?

Comment: Can updating your Python extension or using the pre-release version solve the problem?